# how to get json keys when im getting the json content in string format?

Tags: java, json, rest

Im getting my json in string format from the URI .

```
String srvdiagJson = getJsonFromHttpConnection(diagcon);
```

my json data looks like this.

```
{"hdd_errors":18446744073709552000,"vnet2_tx_packets":86647,"vnet2_rx":19753895921,"vda_write":2873672704,"hdd_read":180702,"vnet2_tx":15722682,"vnet2_rx_drop":691,"vnet2_rx_errors":0,"memory-swap_in":0,"hdd_read_req":78,"vnet2_tx_drop":0,"vnet2_tx_errors":0,"hdd_write":0,"memory":2097152,"memory-rss":1598552,"cpu0_time":48668260000000,"vda_read":251817472,"vda_write_req":267405,"vnet2_rx_packets":225351039,"memory-actual":2097152,"hdd_write_req":0,"vda_read_req":16222,"vda_errors":18446744073709552000}
```

I think there is no need of parsing the data.But i also tried parsing it on advice and kept it in both object and array. but i am unable to access any values.

Comment: how did you parse  the JSON ? What libs did you use and into which data structure did you save it ? Did you create a custom POJO where you stored this data ? Can you share more code to give any insights ?

Comment: If you don't want to parse the json, you want to use regex?

Comment: Furthermore, typing "Json to String Java" into google isn't a bad idea, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jackson? You could try one of the following approaches to get the keys from your JSON:

### Parsing JSON into a `JsonNode`

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);

Iterator<String> it = root.fieldNames();
while (it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

### Parsing JSON into a `Map<String, Object>`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

TypeReference<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> typeReference 
    = new TypeReference<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>() {};
Map<String, Object> root = mapper.readValue(json, typeReference);

root.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Both solutions require [`jackson-databind`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jackson to convert json string to java object and viceversa. e.g

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStr = "{"hdd_errors":18446744073709552000,"vnet2_tx_packets":86647,"vnet2_rx":19753895921,"vda_write":2873672704,"hdd_read":180702,"vnet2_tx":15722682,"vnet2_rx_drop":691,"vnet2_rx_errors":0,"memory-swap_in":0,"hdd_read_req":78,"vnet2_tx_drop":0,"vnet2_tx_errors":0,"hdd_write":0,"memory":2097152,"memory-rss":1598552,"cpu0_time":48668260000000,"vda_read":251817472,"vda_write_req":267405,"vnet2_rx_packets":225351039,"memory-actual":2097152,"hdd_write_req":0,"vda_read_req":16222,"vda_errors":18446744073709552000}";

//JSON from String to Object
HddError obj = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, HddError.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Imports:

> ```
> import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
> import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
> import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
> ```

Code snippet:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonStr);
    Iterator<String> it = jsonNode.fieldNames();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next()); // Printing JSON KEYS
    }
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Implemented the parsing using [Jackson parser](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.2.3)